# Variables, NSInteger not working in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsinteger

Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'UILabel *' is disallowed with ARC
Ok so this is what I am trying to do- I am following a tutorial on youtube and I have a label on ViewController on Xcode's storyboard and am trying to keep a "high score" on the first screen (view controller) using a label and .text (see below):

```
  HighScore =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
    HighScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %li", (long)HighScore];
```

I did declare NSInteger = HighScore in my .h file and it is included but I still get the "Implicit conversion" error report. Any Clues what's going on?

Comment: High score is an integer right? An integer doesn't have a text property. That second line needs to have the name of your label property.text not HighScore.text

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @rdelmar Based on the message: "Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'UILabel *'" this means that `HighScore` is a `UILabel` since the message means that the code is trying to assign an `NSInteger` (from the `integerForKey:` call) to a `UILabel *` (`HighScore`) in the 1st line of the posted code.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWcEwErcMxs

Comment: OMy gosh my bad guys I named the UILabel and NSInt the same thing on accident so i suppose you were both right

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks, I guess I didn't read that error message close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `HighScore` variable is a `UILabel`. You can't assign the value from `NSUserDefaults` to the label.

Try this:

```
NSInteger score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
HighScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %li", (long)score];
```

BTW - consider using standard naming conventions. Variable and method names should begin with lowercase letters. Class names begin with Uppercase letters.

Comment: yeah i usually do but i am new to Xcode and following the tutorial basically to the letter haha

Comment: can you share the link to the tutorial? @PICKme